# injective bounded linear operator with image contained in a closed subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $T:H\rightarrow H$ be a injective, bounded linear operator. Suppose the range of $T$ is contained inside a closed subspace of $H$, is that closed subspace $H$ itself?

It seems to me that this must be true. Since $T$ is injective, it maps every vector to a unique vector, and the range is not dense if the closed subspace is proper. But it seems so good to be true.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you asking whether the range is a closed subspace ? That's  not true in general.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc No, I am asking if the image is contained in a closed subspace, the closed subspace can be proper or not, the range itself may not be closed.

Comment: The range is always contained in its closure. If the range is not dense, then the closure is a proper subspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On $\ell^{2}$ define $T(x_n)=(0,x_1,x_2,....)$. Then $T$ is bounded, injective and its range is $\{(x_n): x_1=0\}$ which is a proper closed subsapce.